# How to await the loading of the *next* page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, tampermonkey

I'm trying to write a script in the [TamperMonkey browser extension](https://www.tampermonkey.net) that will perform tasks across multiple pages on a website. Its first task is to find and click a link on the main page of the website. I found out I need the script to be able to wait for the next page to fully load before the script begins to attempt to carry out its next actions.

Can someone give me a code snippet that accomplishes the task of waiting for the next page to load? If that ask is too cheap, could I persuade you to let me know whether studying, for example, *promises* will get me where I'm trying to go or, if not, point me to the topic(s) that can. I'm not a programmer by trade but a dilettante and my area of interest is not even JavaScript.

I tried studying and using promises / and async/await statements but became so lost and confused that I don't even know how to share an example of how I tried to apply those language features to my use case.

Comment: does `the next page` refer to a whole new page being loaded (like when you click on an actual navigation link) or does the click result in updating the current page through some sort AJAX type request?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks -- I believe `the next page` is an entirely new page.

Comment: then your userscript is freshly loaded (assuming the new page is a valid target for your userscript) and needs to wait for DOMContentLoaded - or there is a setting in the manifest as to when the script is run - I can't recall, haven't greasemonkey'd in years. *edit:* `// @run-at document-end` I believe - *edit 2:* and yes, I said greasemonkey instead of tampermonkey - that's how long I've used userscripts :p

Comment: Interesting -- let me tinker with that lead you've just given me and report back.  My turn to *edit*: deep bow at your mention of GreaseMonkey ;-)